# How do I parse aws CLI output using queries?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to run an AWS CLI query to return some data from Inspector.

```
aws inspector2 list-findings \
    --query 'findings[*].{Severity:severity,Title:title,Instance:resources.id,Type:resources.type}' \
    --output table
```

It will populate the Severity and Title columns, but Instance and Type are returning "None" values.  I know that my query is incorrect because if I run it like so:

```
aws inspector2 list-findings \
    --query 'findings[*].resources[*].{Severity:severity,Title:title,Instance:id,Type:type}' \
    --output table
```

It will return Instance and Type values and "None" for Severity and Title.

Can someone please provide guidance as to how to run this query successfully?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resources attribute is a list, so you need to parse through it with [*] as follows

```
 aws inspector2 list-findings --query 'findings[*].{Severity:severity,Title:title,Instance:resources[*].id,Type:resources[*].type}' --output table
```

Greetings!